# Map JSON Object To Something Worthwhile in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I was wondering if I could get a little advice on pulling in some JSON data in my React app. I have a good amount of experience in front end development, but unfortunately have minimal knowledge when it comes to pulling in data from remote resources.

Here is my sample json data

```
{
  "hello": {
    "yo" : "random",
    "hey" : "cool"
  }
}
```

This data sits locally and I can pull it in just fine, but I am wondering if there is an easier way to get the data into the format I want. My code is below of what I am doing,

```
 grabData() {
    axios.get('data.json')
      .then(function(response) {
        var info = response.data.hello;
        info = Object.values(info);

        this.setState({ info : info })
      });
  }
```

For those unfamiliar, I am using an ES6 feature to turn the object into an array so I can use the map method in a child component that will receive this array.

However, I think this method is flawed, as it completely strips the object of its keys, which I would like to keep intact to use in the map method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS. Is it really necessary for me to use "response.data.hello" to access the object?

Comment: Please include code as text, not a picture.

Comment: There we go, fixed it.

Comment: `Object.keys(info).map(key => info[key], key)`

Comment: Hey azium, thanks for the reply, could you give a quick description of what that is doing? It might help others out. If it makes sense, I'd be glad to give it an upvote.

Comment: Is your question, "How do I loop over an object to get both its keys and values?"

Comment: `Object.keys(info)` will return an _array_ of keys of info object.
Like this `['yo', 'hey']`. Now you can map over this array and get the values by passing each key on object with `info[key]` like `info['yo']`

Comment: @azium yes thats the question. Your solution and Hiren's description seem to help, I can't test it out until tomorrow, but will leave a comment about how it worked out.

Comment: It's very unclear exactly what you're trying to do. You say "how do I get it into the format that I want" but don't go into any specifics about what you want. Give a clear description and example of the intended output given an example input.